# Telerik MVC Grid row values failing after group by

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I have Telerik MVC grid in my view.

[image]

I'm binding the column "Debit Balance" value with calculation in my client side and data binding properly ,here is how i bind data

```
//my grid
    @( Html.Telerik().Grid<Orpac.Models.E_GetCarHar_Result>()
                     .Name("grdAccTransactions").NoRecordsTemplate("No record to display")
                     .Localizable("")

                     .HtmlAttributes("width: 100%;cellpadding:0;")
                     .Columns(columns =>
                     {
                         columns.Bound(e => e.CrhIdent).Hidden().IncludeInContextMenu(false);
                         columns.Bound(e => e.CrhTip).Hidden().IncludeInContextMenu(false);
                         columns.Bound(e => e.CrhTarih).Title((string)ViewData["Date"]);
                         columns.Bound(e => e.CrhTipNam).Title((string)ViewData["Description"]);
                         columns.Bound(e => e.CrhRef).Title((string)ViewData["Ref"]);
                         columns.Bound(e => e.CrhIslem).Hidden().IncludeInContextMenu(false);
                         columns.Bound(e => e.CrhDvzTut).Title((string)ViewData["Amount"]);
                         columns.Bound(e => e.CrhYrlTut).Title((string)ViewData["DebitBalance"]);
                         columns.Bound(e => e.CrhVade).Title((string)ViewData["DueDate"]);
                     })                 
                     .DataBinding(d => d.Ajax().Select("GridAccountTransactionBinding", "Transaction"))
                     .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("onRowDataBoundAccTrans").OnLoad("onloadaccountTR").OnRowSelect("onRowSelectaccountTR"))
                     .Selectable()
                     .Sortable()
                     .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled((bool)ViewData["paging"]).PageSize(10))
                     .Groupable(grouping => grouping.Enabled((bool)ViewData["grouping"]))
                     .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled((bool)ViewData["filtering"]))
                     .Footer(((bool)ViewData["showFooter"]))
                     .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(330))
                     .Resizable(config =>
                     {
                         config.Columns(true);
                     })
                     .Reorderable(config =>
                     {
                         config.Columns(true);
                     })
                    .ColumnContextMenu()
                   )
//this is how to bind grid


    [GridAction(GridName = "grdAccTransactions")]
    public ActionResult GridAccountTransactionBinding()
    {
                    E_Get_Result p = new E_Get_Result();
                    p.CrhIdent = item.CrhIdent;
                    p.CrhTarih = item.CrhTarih;
                    p.CrhVade = item.CrhVade;
                    p.CrhRef = item.CrhRef;
                    p.CrhIslem = item.CrhIslem;
                     if (p.CrhIslem == "-")
                    {
                        p.CrhDvzTut = item.CrhDvzTut;
                        p.CrhYrlTut = DebitBalance - item.CrhDvzTut;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        p.CrhDvzTut = (-1)*item.CrhDvzTut;
                        p.CrhYrlTut = DebitBalance + item.CrhDvzTut;
                    }
                    p.Add(list);

        return View(new GridModel<Models.E_GetCarHar_Result>
        {
            Data = list
        });
    }


 //Change DBalance number format in this function
function onRowDataBoundAccTrans(e) {
var decimal = $("#decimal1").text();
var currency = $("#currency1").text();
var dsep = $("#dsep1").text();
var tsep = $("#tsep1").text();
e.row.cells[6].textContent = accounting.formatMoney(e.dataItem.CrhDvzTut, currency, parseInt(decimal), tsep, dsep);
e.row.cells[7].textContent = accounting.formatMoney(e.dataItem.CrhYrlTut, currency,     parseInt(decimal), tsep, dsep);
}
```

but when i group by with any data

My row values binding without calculation? I can trace it with debugger values fetching true but grid doesn't show the same value

After Group by "Debit Balance" value shows uncalculating

[image]

Do you know this reason?

Please help me

Thnx All

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have the problem when doing a sort or filter by operation ?

Comment: No. Its just failing group by operation

Comment: In your second screenshot, I see the Debit Balance column has lost the € symbol. Does it also happen when you do a sort ?
Are you using a Template and a ClientTemplate in your Grid ? Could you post the code you use to declare the Grid in your view ?

Comment: I editted the questions i'm formatting the Debit Balance Value OnRowDataBound function from client side

Comment: I don't see where you calculate the CrhYrlTut property in your binding. And how is handled the Dbalance variable ? Can you edit your post to add the entire GridAccountTransactionBinding action ?

Comment: Maybe your problem comes from your javascript ... I guess we are getting closer now. Is is possible to have the code from your accounting.formatMoney function ? And you didn't reply to all of my questions : I don't see where you get the CrhYrlTut value in your binding, and what is Dbalance (is it a static variable ??)

Comment: Dbalance is a variable create from by me i'm fetching that value from database and give first value then calculate the other values in controller if (p.CrhIslem == "-")
                    {
                        p.CrhDvzTut = item.CrhDvzTut;
                        p.DebitBalance = Dbalance - item.CrhDvzTut;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        p.CrhDvzTut = (-1)*item.CrhDvzTut;
                        p.DebitBalance  = Dbalance  + item.CrhDvzTut;
                    }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49949/discussion-between-darkchico-and-saul)

Comment: this is accounting.FormatMoney function http://josscrowcroft.github.io/accounting.js/

Comment: Yes!!! I found the error @darkchico Error comes from my javascript function of onRowDataBoundAccTrans because i make find staticly row numbers and formatted them then when make group by columns values failing

Comment: Congratulations, I suspected it was coming from a JS, but I couldn't find where :)

Comment: that js effect i'm sure but intersting something inside grid when i make group by my grid data shift to left I will wrote it the other questions and publish here a link